# Show comment associated with "other" reason on close-vote review page

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, vote-to-close, custom-close-reasons

A question in the "Close Votes" review queue has close votes for "Off Topic: Other."  Expanding the close reason summary by clicking on "(more)" shows:

[image]

The summary does not show the comment(s) that have been attached to the "other" reason:

```
"Off Topic: Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)"
```

Can the summary at the top of the CV review page please be changed to show the reason or reasons that have been given for the "Other" votes, like this?:

```
"Off Topic: Other (Asker has shown no effort to solve the problem)"
```

Comment: It is also available as a comment under the question, right? I normally hit PgDn if I can't see them due to a lengthy post. A custom close reason can't be overlooked in the comments

Comment: @rene The custom close reason is _not_ available as a comment on the question which prompted this request (I have not linked to the question to avoid the meta effect).  Whether the custom reason was once there as a comment and has been deleted, or was never there, I cannot tell.

Comment: OK, that makes sense and clarifies the FR.

Comment: Hey there, just a quick clarification question. Did you edit the screenshot to redact the off topic reason, or does SO actually show an empty white box like in your screenshot? I tried to reproduce but after a bunch of tries I wasn't able to get a question flagged this way, so I'm hoping you can clarify this for me. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasOrozco No, no editing of the screenshot.  However, I only just now noticed the empty white box... isn't that interesting.  Do you suppose this is a browser issue?  I was using Google Chrome 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit).  Unfortunately, I don't know how to get back to that question so that I can try it in different browsers, etc.

Comment: @WayneConrad So, to make sure I fully understand you: your request is that we add the reason that was typed in by the user where we currently have an empty white box? (assuming this box isn't a bug to begin with, which to be entirely honest — I don't know right now)

Comment: @ThomasOrozco My request--supposing that this isn't a bug--is that the custom reason(s) given for the close reason "off-topic/other" be shown somewhere in the "This question has been flagged as" summary.  I don't think it really matters whether it's in the white box or not--just that it's visible somewhere.